# How to define a relationship with builtin User entity in jhipster jdl?

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

The following

```
>yo jhipster:import-jdl model.jdl

entity Car{
brand String
 }

relationship  ManyToOne{
    Car{owner} to User
}
```

return parsing error:

```
ERROR! Error while parsing entities from JDL
[object Object]
```

The same relationship can be built using the command line. Is there a way to define this relationship in the JDL ?

jhipster 3.5.1

Comment: what is the detail in parsing error?

Comment: @ismail posted above

Comment: If there is could you please post all error log, because this only means there is a paring error which you already stated

Comment: Where do I find that ?

Comment: where did you get this error in terminal/console?

Comment: Yes, in bash on "yo jhipster:import-jdl jdlfile"

Comment: I tried node --debuge, but did not get any more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120152/discussion-between-ismail-and-nabil-sham).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error, and a solution, at lest for my case ;)

```
$ yo jhipster:import-jdl ./entities-jdl.jh
The jdl is being parsed.
Error jhipster:import-jdl ./entities-jdl.jh 

ERROR! Error while parsing entities from JDL
[object Object]
```

1. Add only few entities or relationships in the file (entities-jdl.jh)
2. Run again yo jhipster:import-jdl ./entities-jdl.jh
3. Repeat until you find the error
4. Analyse the syntax of the lasts entities or relationship you added

In my case the JDL error was in this entity:

```
entity Serie {
    tipus TipusSerie required maxlength(20),
    nom String required,
    prefixe String required
}

enum TipusSerie {
    NORMAL, XEC_ESCOLETA
}
```

TipusSerie is an enum and cannot be validated with maxlength(20), so the correct JDL is:

```
entity Serie {
    tipus TipusSerie required,
    nom String required,
    prefixe String required
}

enum TipusSerie {
    NORMAL, XEC_ESCOLETA
}
```

I suposse that jhipster hasn't an error messages for that kind of error and shows a generic error message.